# Is there any major change in xcode 3 and xcode 4.3.2, Is ideveloper.tv tutorials are useless/less useful now?

Tags: ios, xcode4, xcode4.2

*PS: I am 3 years+ experienced ruby on rails developer, Just started with iPhone development.*

I bought membership for [Objective C](http://ideveloper.tv/video/objectiveccourse.html) and [iOS development](http://ideveloper.tv/video/iosdevelopmentcourse.html) by [Ideveloper.tv](http://ideveloper.tv/). Got to know about these from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/how-to-articles-for-iphone-development-and-objective-c) question. I am also having membership for [thinkvitamin](http://thinkvitamin.com/) video series.ThinkVitamin and iDeveloper.tv both are using xcode 3 and I am having xcode 4.

I am confused in getting the file structure tree. For example xcode 4 is not having resources group directory.(Atleast for a beginer like me its not, specially when you are trying to understand things from videos and try it out those things on your machine.)

[image]

This is just a beginning right now. I dont want to invest time on understanding whats changed, keep googling every 10 mins for how this can be done in Xcode4 etc (for now only, later on I will check.)
So the point is:

- Is there any big change between Xcode 3 and Xcode 4.2?
- What you guys suggest to buy some other membership which has latest video series, if yes, which one? or no these videos are fine just follow some these(?) steps in between, cause initially if you keep facing these stupid issues, you keep losing interest. So i want to make initial few hours of learning smooth just to get a real feel of iOS.

*PS: I am open for buying some another membership. Point is the time. I am already having too much work at my office, so wants to make best possible use of limited available time.*

Comment: "Is there any big change between Xcode 3 and Xcode 4.2" You mean, like a whole UI rewrite and regrouping of stuff?

Comment: Yes. Like i can't see any resource group in my project in Xcode4 and thats y not able to find *.xib file for interface editor etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any big change between Xcode 3 and Xcode 4.2?

Xcode 4 was/is a major update, it was all about big changes! You can't directly compare the interface of Xcode 4 to the one of Xcode 3, so trying to learn Xcode 4 with videos about Xcode 3 is a really bad idea, especially if you have no previous experience with Xcode!

> What you guys suggest to buy some other membership which has latest video series

Yes, or the guides from Apple directly. They are free, and cover every little detail!

Also, you actual problem, the missing xib files, have nothing to do with Xcode 4 vs Xcode 3, but you created an iOS 5 application which now uses Storyboards instead of normal xibs (and while you can change it back, your video tutorial doesn't tell you anything about it because not only does it focus on an outdate Xcode version, but also on an outdated iOS version)

Comment: Thats actually I was worried about, It seems like same with Rails2 and Rails3. Thanks a lot for your answer.